# Using Stimulreport on remote virtual machine

Tags: c#, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, stimulsoft

I have a C# program in MS Framework 4.0 that use StimulSoft Report 2010 to show and print some reports.
My program work quite right in my computer, but when I try to run it on a **remote virtual computer** it has problem and give me this error:

```
Application: MyApplication.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
Stack:
at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Load(System.String)
at Tavanmand.StoneCut.ManagementApplication.SlabForm.PrintForm(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, System.Windows.RoutedEvent)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr, System.Windows.Input.InputMode, Int32, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions, Int32, Int32, Int32)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run()
at Tavanmand.StoneCut.ManagementApplication.App.Main()
```

I just have problem with this part of my program. Other parts are working well.
I had been add all the stimulreport dll files near myApplication.exe and even install *StimulSoft Report 2010* but it still doesn't work.

What should I do now?

Comment: The final call in the stack trace is when you try to load your report file. (the MRT). Are you sure that you have setup the correct file and path on your remote machine.

Comment: @Steve: yeah, thanks. Infact I forgot to copy folder of my .mrt files; and it solved my problem. but I still have another question: did I have to install stimulreport or a copy of its dll files near myApplication.exe is enought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final call in the stack trace is when you try to load your report file. (the MRT).

This seems a clear sign that you don't have correctly setup the folder where you search for your report files and thus you get the exception

```
Directory Not Found
```

For your second comment, absolutely yes.
You need to redistribute the DLL required by your project. If you look at the programming manual you will find a section dedicated to the redistribution of the assembly. They change according to your kind of project. (Section `21.12 Redistributable files in Reports.Net`)

The Stimulsoft files can be simply copied in the same folder where you have installed your application. Of course you could also add them to the GAC of the target machine. But I find simpler to copy them in the same folder of the application